# What is the best line of the Colle to play against KID set up by Black?

Tags: opening, colle-system

Playing the Colle, if Black plays g6 and then Bg7 what is the best line for White?

Comment: King’s Indian Defense Colle-Zukertort System (1.d4 d5 2.Nf3 e6 3.e3 Nf6 4.Bd3 c5 5.b3 Nc6 6.0-0 Bd6 7.Bb2 0-0)? Can you add a pgn or something, I’m not sure when black plays the move. Can you add if it follows the normal Colle system, if the lines transpose to it, or just an example of the game or something

Comment: 1d4 d5 2.Nf3 Nf6.3e3 g6 4Bd3 (?) Bg7 etc

Comment: When you say KID setup I assume you mean with d6 as well, while the other comments with d5 are Grunfeld setup.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I'm puzzled how to play Colle against Grunfeld and KID set ups by Black

Answer (score 2):

The English GM Simon Williams has just [tweeted this](https://twitter.com/ginger_gm/status/984434599739691008) -

> Just finished filming 'The Colle' a DVD for @ChessBase. I must say
>   that the Colle with 1 d4 2 Nf3 3 e3 4 c3 5 Nd2 and 6 Bd3 is basically
>   rubbish. But the 'Colle-Zukertort' with 4 b3 is another matter
>   entirely... Learnt a lot filming this week.

That sounds reasonable to me. In other words you are wasting your time.

In general the answer to the question "Given that I always play opening X how should I use opening X to reply to opening Y by my opponent?" is nearly always something along the lines of - "You should not dogmatically play opening X in all circumstances. You should always play the position in front of you and try and find the best moves. If your opponent plays something against which your standard opening is rubbish then play something else."

Against the KID the Colle is a silly opening to play. The same could probably be said of the London. Classical lines involving putting your pawns on c4, d4 and e4 with a knight on c3 can't be bad but obviously there is a lot to learn.

If you want to frighten your opponent and take him out of his comfort zone then something like the Barry / 150 attack should do the job. That is where you play d4, Bf4, Nf3 following up with e4 if your opponent doesn't play d5 and then aiming for Qd2, 0-0-0 and an early h4.

I believe that along with the Colle DVD he has also been working on a DVD about the Torre attack. When these are released (probably take a couple of months for Chessbase to do their editing, tidying up and marketing) you might be interested.

Disclaimer: I have nothing to do with either Chessbase or Simon Williams although I have bought their DVDs in the past.

Comment: Thankyou. I'll definitely watch out for tha delayed Grunfeld or KID by Black does make life very difficult for Colle playe DVD. I agree the Barry/150 is a good option against g6 and Bg7 but the problem arises after White 3e3, typical Colle move,  when White has locked in his B and only then Black plays g6 etc.  I don't agree that Colle is basically rubbish , and C-Z is even more dynamic but  a delayed Grunfeld or KID is problematic and hence I'm looking for help.